# MX OTT TV Box PIN Problem

Tags: mx-player

My box boots directly into the pin entry screen, Clock on left and keypad on the right.

I enter the pin correctly and the home screen comes up for one second and then goes back to the pin entry screen. I can't get it to do anything else.

The PIN is correct, If I leave it for a few seconds it just goes into the default screensaver.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem today. I typed in `1234` for the PIN and it worked, but I don't know why or how.

Comment: mine is doing this too, tried 1234 but its not working

Comment: 1234 Worked for me ;)